# How to return data in another function from a SQLite query in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, sqlite, asynchronous

i'm new to React Native, i'm trying to extrapolate a data from a query, but "return" doesn't work. Maybe because it required the promises, i tried but i'm not good enough. I call the function in the View component of the App function (in App.js) like this

```
<View>Search()</View>
```

but nothing is shown. If i put the console.log in search() (in another function) i can see the result, but i can't return it in my App.js (the function is correctly imported into the App)

```
export function Search() {

        db.transaction(
          (tx) => {
            tx.executeSql("select pver from profile where id=12524234", [],
            (tx, results) => {
              var a = JSON.stringify(results.rows._array[0].pver)
              var data = Number(a)
              return data;
            });
          },
          null,
        )
      };
```

This is how i've tried to do on advice of a user

```
//this in App.js
import {Search} from './Funzioni'

export default function App() {
const [searchResult, setSearchResult] = useState();


useEffect(() => {
  console.log("we are in the useeffect")
    Search().then((data)=>{
      console.log("set") //doesn't appear
        setSearchResult(data)
 })
},[]);

//other codes

return (<View>{searchResult}</View> )
}



//this in "Funzioni.js"

 export async function Search() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            db.transaction(
                (tx) => {
                  tx.executeSql("select pver from profile where id=12524234", [],
                  (tx, results) => {
                    var a = JSON.stringify(results.rows._array[0].pver)
                    var data = Number(a)
                    console.log("the data: " + data) //doesn't appear
                    resolve(data);
                  });
                },
                null,
              )
        });
      };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transaction method is asynchronous when you render your component the search function still hasn't resolved.

In your component you should use useState to store the data and useEffect to fetch the data

```
const [searchResult, setSearchResult] = useState('');
useEffect(() => {
    Search().then((data)=>{
        setSearchResult(data)
    }).catch((error) => console.log(error));
},[]);
return <View>{searchResult}</View>
```

Your Search function should be like this

```
export async function Search() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const db = SQLite.openDatabase('THE_NAME_OF_YOUR_DATABASE.db')
        db.transaction(
            (tx) => {
              tx.executeSql("select pver from profile where id=12524234", [],
              (tx, results) => {
                var a = JSON.stringify(results.rows._array[0].pver)
                var data = Number(a)
                resolve(data);
              },
              function (error) {
                  reject(false);
                  throw new Error(
                      'Error: ' + error
                  );
              });
            },
            function (error) {
                reject(undefined);
                throw new Error('error: ' + error.message);
            },
            function () {
                console.log('ok');
            }
          )
    });
  };
```

Comment: i've tried, but gives me this error _Funzioni.Search.then is not a function. (In '_Funzioni.Search.then(function (data) {
        setSearchResult(data);
      })', '_Funzioni.Search.then' is undefined). Funzioni is the js where the Search function is located

Comment: Sorry I fixed it, it's Search().then( ....

Comment: now there'aren't errors, but it can't exevute the Search function. I put some logs, it starts the useEffect, but it never do Search nor setSearchResult. (thank you anyway for the help you giving to me)

Comment: Can you edit your question with the code you have now, with the logs

Comment: done. on the log lines that do not appear I commented with "doesn't appear"

Comment: Just to make sure, your code in App.js is inside your app component?

Comment: yes, it's under "export default function App() {"

Comment: Ok try the new Search function and tell me which error you get

Comment: now i get this warning: "[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Error: [object Object]]", in the emulator says "Possible Unhandled promise rejection (id: 0)" and another with id:1

Comment: Did you create the database profile?

Comment: yes, if i do a normal executeSql and put the data in a console log, next if i trigger the function by a button the console show me 4 (which is the correct number). Wait, now i put the entire App.js code in the post

Comment: Now it WORKED! i skipped a character the last time i pasted your code. Thank you very much!